# Changing resolution for compiled application / game via asembler?

Tags: c++, assembly, screen, screen-resolution

I want to know, if there is any way to force a new resolution for example 1920x1080 for compiled game/application which was compiled years ago? I think it could be done via assembler but i'm not sure. Can anyone tell something about this? (Game created in C++ and using dx9)

Comment: To use such a high resolution you have to use the BIOS Vesa extensions of the interrupt 10h. The highest resoultions you could use without Vesa are th e video mode 19 (13h) which is 320x200 pixels with 256 colors and video mode 17 (11h) which is monochrome with 640x480 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

No, it is not easy.  At a bare minimum, you'll need to find where the screen resolution is selected and change it to provide the new resolution.  If you're lucky, that's the only change you'll need to make; more likely, assumptions about the resolution are scattered throughout the code (buffer sizes, UI locations, etc.) and any pre-rendered graphics.